# PHP Unset sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a php page called `automate.php` where i include multiple php files - for example:

```
customer_reminders_1.php
customer_reminders_2.php
customer_reminders_3.php
```

each one has the same queries in but searching from different fields in a table.

i have a feeling, that if there are valid rows from the returned query in more than one of the above pages they are getting confused with each other.

for example, there is `$sql="SELECT * from table...` on all 3 and while loops etc.

whats the best way to unset the variables after the query has been run or something i can add in the automate.php where the files are included to stop them getting mixed together?

Comment: if i put $sql=''; $sql2=''; after each include in automate.php will this work?

Answer (score 1):

try using unset() function to unset sql query

```
 unset($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `unset()` (http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) between the `include`s?

Edit: Of course you need to specify all variables you want to unset.